# Crear una apk en ionic. error al ejecutar build

Tags: ionic3, ionic-framework

Al intentar crear una apk para probarlo en el móvil me sale el siguiente error.

Los pasos que sigo son los siguientes pero en el ultimo paso me da error.

> ionic cordova platform rm android
>
> ionic cordova platform add android
>
> ionic cordova build android

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: instalastes el jdk de java?

Comment: Hola. Si ya he instalado, pero ahor me sale otro error.

Comment: el error te dice que te falta una dependencia , ejecuta el comando `npm install -g @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev`

Comment: Si añadi ese comando no se ni cuantas veces. Pero el error persiste. No se si es porque lo estoy creando en windows

Comment: Eso no tiene nada que ver... Comprueba que tienes la variable de entorno JAVA_HOME apuntando al sitio correcto.

Comment: Pues no tengo ni idea como puedo saber si apunta a dicho entorno de variable. Si quieres te paso el teamviewer y ves el error. Me dice que build failed